# insert query working, update not working?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

This insert program work perfect
But same as update not working any body help to give correct code

**Insert.php**

```
 <html>
 <form role="form" action="" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name..." id="fname">
 <input list="dept" placeholder="Choose Dept"  name="dept" required/>
 <datalist id="dept">
 <option>
 <?php 
  include 'dblayer.php';
  $query = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT department FROM department");
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
       echo "<option value='". $row['department']."'>".$row['department'] .'</option>';
    }
  ?>
  </option>
  </datalist>

<?php
include "dblayer.php";
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $fname  = $_POST["fname"];
    $dept   = $_POST["dept"];
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO employee(fname,department)
            SELECT '$fname', dept_id  FROM department WHERE department = '$dept' LIMIT 1");

    if($result)
        {
            echo "<script>alert('New employee register successfully!')</script>";
            echo "<script>window.open('home.php','_self')</script>";
        }
    else 
        {
            echo "<script>alert('something went wrong!')</script>";
        }
    }
?>
```

**Update.php**

This page join query some problem. I think department values get but not save record. So join query correct format answer give anybody

```
 <?php
 include 'dblayer.php';
 $action = isset( $_POST['action'] ) ? $_POST['action'] : "";
 if($action == "update")
  { 
    $query = "UPDATE employee SET fname = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['fname'])."', department='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['department'])."' where id='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id'])."'";
   if( $mysqli->query($query) ) {
        echo "<script>alert('updated!')</script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('insert.php')</script>";}
  else{
       echo "Unable to update record.";
       }}
    $query = "SELECT  employee.fname, department.department FROM employee    INNER JOIN department ON 
    employee.department = department.dept_id 
    WHERE 
    employee.id='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id'])."'limit 0,1";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $fname = $row['fname'];
    $dept = $row['department'];
?>
```

Comment: Does your `update` query work? It looks like it has a siglequotes-doublequotes issue..

Comment: department values not updated.
because dept field another table.
foreign key join and get values.
but not updated.

Comment: departnment field enter INT values it stored.

Comment: You are mixing "dept" and "department". Use the same name everywhere.

Comment: yes i agree but now the department all follow at unique

Comment: please verify (update query only problem) in my suggession

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<input list="dept" placeholder="Choose Dept"  name="dept" required/>
```

to

```
<input list="dept" placeholder="Choose Dept"  name="department" required/>
```

And in your insert script: `$dept = $_POST["department"];`

Comment: yes this one changed because update table <input> all department only

Comment: any onchange function or update query with join table give the solution please . I am trying to last one week in this CRUD operation

Comment: No body don t know update query?
Please tell me how to write the update query

Comment: yes department value not updating. remaining fields all update working

Comment: Before update query will you do `print_r($_POST);` and let me know the result of that?

Comment: department field in integer. i have get department values all in another table string values. so now join use update.

but never understand my doubt

Comment: I understand your issue but what is the output of `print_r($_POST);`